# Why does Insert Into statement create a new row?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

My insert into statement is creating a new row. I think it is because of the if statement.

Here is an example of my code:

```
Dim blanco = "Ja"
Dim blanco1 = "Nee"

With cmd
    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Workflow ([DossierPad]) VALUES ('" + Mid(stukjes(0), 1, 58) + "')"
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Data ([DossierPad], [Tif], [Grootte]) VALUES ('" + Mid(stukjes(0), 1, 58) + "','" + Mid(stukjes(0), 59, 71) + "','" + stukjes(2) + "')"
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
    If stukjes(2) < 20000 Then
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Data ([Blanco]) VALUES ('" + blanco + "')"
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Data ([Blanco]) VALUES ('" + blanco1 + "')"
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
End With
```

Insert into data `[Blanco]`, which is within the if statement creates a new row in my database.

Here is a picture of what happens every time I try to insert something:

[image]

As you see the database creates a new row, but must be within the same row.

Comment: Maybe you should read something about SQL. There are only a few keywords in this language, but you should know them.

Comment: Why would you be surprised that an `INSERT` statement inserts a record? If you want to update a record then use an `UPDATE` statement. This is the absolute basics of SQL so you really ought to work through a beginners tutorial, e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/default.asp

Comment: Thought an Insert statement in a row that is still empty would insert in there, sorry new to programma still a student. @jmcilhinney

Comment: @Klaas-JelleRas consider looking into using parameters as well instead of string concatenation.

Comment: @Bugs The code must be as short as possible so I did not add parameters.

Comment: @Klaas-JelleRas the reason for parameters is to stop SQL injection and to reduce syntax issues. I appreciate it can create a little more code but it's well worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very normal. I think you didn't read much about [SQL Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp).

**Insert** is used to add a new row to a database.

**Update** is used to change data.

In your code you first do:

```
"INSERT INTO Data ([DossierPad], [Tif], [Grootte]) VALUES ('" + Mid(stukjes(0), 1, 58) + "','" + Mid(stukjes(0), 59, 71) + "','" + stukjes(2) + "')"
```

And then you do:

```
"INSERT INTO Data ([Blanco]) VALUES ('" + blanco + "')"
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Hence you have two inserts.

if you just want to change the blanco you need **Update** statement:

```
If stukjes(2) < 20000 Then
    .CommandText = "UPDATE Data SET Blanco = '" & blanco & "' WHERE DossierPad = '" & Mid(stukjes(0), 1, 58) & "'"
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
Else
    .CommandText = "UPDATE Data SET Blanco = '" & blanco1 & "' WHERE DossierPad = '" & Mid(stukjes(0), 1, 58) & "'"
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
End If
```

**Note:**

- As Abbas pointed out this is only good practice if DossierPad is **UNIQUE**
- Otherwise use a Primary Key to make sure you don't update the wrong row

Comment: I like your answer, but what if several rows in the table have the same `DossierPad`. Such fields shouldn't be used as identifiers.

Comment: @Abbas yeah i totally agree but in his screenshot I didn't see and **primary key** field :/ so can't do much more with a poorly structure db

Comment: @Abbas added little note about it ;)

Answer (score 1):

After executing an `INSERT` statement to create a new row in the Workflow and the Data table, you are using an INSERT again inside the If-Else statement. Logically, this will create a new row again.

To update an existing row, you need to use the `UPDATE` keyword. Here's the syntax for the update query:

```
UPDATE table
SET column1 = expression1,
    column2 = expression2,
    ...
[WHERE conditions];
```

This makes me also wonder why you don't insert the value already in the first INSERT query.